# Android RxJava subscribe triggered from nowhere

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, rx-java2

I have a simple app that displays contact list pulled from an API.
I need to display the latest contacts fetch if there is no network at the launch of the app. So that's why I'm working with Room to save the contacts into a database.

The contacts are correctly saved, they are correctly pulled when needed.
But there is a weird problem when I do the following pattern:
 - I pull some contacts from the API (auto-saved into the local db)
 - I kill the app;
 - I cut all network to trigger the pull from the local db;
 - I launch the app without any network, contacts are correctly displayed from the local db;
 - I open the network to process a fresh call to the API (clean the db and so on...)
 - After the response to the call to the API, after the subscribe of the `getContacts` call, the subscribe of the getContactsFromDatabase is called !!

So after debugging I found that just the subscribe is called and not the full function `getContactsFromDatabase()` because of my breakpoint on the `srList.isRefreshing = true` is not triggered. Only the breakpoint in the subscribe part.

I also tried to put a breakpoint to the only part where the getContactsFromDatabase function is called. It's never triggered however the breakpoint in the subscribe is triggered.

You can check my code on [Github](https://github.com/alexandre-thauvin/contact_list)

ContactListFragment.kt:

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            dataStorage = DataStorage(requireContext())
            initView()
            initListeners()
        }

        private fun initView() {
            val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            rvContact.layoutManager = layoutManager
            rvContact.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
            adapter = ContactListAdapter(this::onContactClicked)
            rvContact.adapter = adapter
            getContacts()
        }

        private fun initListeners() {
            srList.setOnRefreshListener {
                viewModel.page = 1; viewModel.contacts.clear(); getContacts()
            }

            rvContact.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                    val manager = rvContact.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
                    val visibleItemCount: Int = manager.childCount
                    val totalItemCount: Int = manager.itemCount
                    val firstVisibleItemPosition: Int = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                    if (!srList.isRefreshing) {
                        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                            && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                            && totalItemCount >= ContactListViewModel.PAGE_SIZE
                        ) {
                            getContacts()
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        private fun getContacts() {
            srList.isRefreshing = true
            disposable.add(viewModel.getContactByPages()
                .doOnError { e ->
                    srList.isRefreshing = false
                    if (viewModel.launch){
                        Timber.e("get contacts database")//breakpoint not triggered
                        getContactsFromDatabase()
                    }
                    e.localizedMessage?.let {
                        Timber.e(it)
                    }
                    val message = when (e) {
                        is BadRequestException -> {
                            getString(R.string.common_error_bad_request)
                        }
                        is ServerErrorException -> {
                            getString(R.string.common_error_server_error)
                        }
                        is UnknownHostException -> {
                            getString(R.string.common_error_no_connection)
                        }
                        else -> {
                            getString(R.string.common_error_basic)
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                .subscribe({ result ->
                    srList.isRefreshing = false
                    viewModel.page++
                    if (dataStorage.getBoolean(IS_FROM_CACHE)){//need a variable to clean the database after a first successful fetch
                        dataStorage.putBoolean(IS_FROM_CACHE, false).subscribe()
                        viewModel.contacts.clear()
                        cleanContactListOfDatabase()
                    }
                    viewModel.contacts.addAll(result.contacts)
                    saveContactsToDatabase()
                    adapter.updateList(viewModel.contacts)
                    tvNumberOfResult.text = getString(
                        R.string.contact_list_fragment_number_of_result,
                        viewModel.contacts.size
                    )
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
            )
        }

        private fun getContactsFromDatabase() {
            srList.isRefreshing = true//breakpoint not triggered here
            disposable.add(viewModel.getContactFromDatabase()
                .doOnError {
                    srList.isRefreshing = false
                }
                .subscribe({
                    srList.isRefreshing = false// breakpoint triggered here
                        viewModel.launch = false
                        viewModel.contacts.addAll(it)
                        adapter.updateList(viewModel.contacts)
                        tvNumberOfResult.text = getString(
                            R.string.contact_list_fragment_number_of_result,
                            viewModel.contacts.size
                        )
                        dataStorage.putBoolean(IS_FROM_CACHE, true).subscribe()
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
            )
        }

        private fun saveContactsToDatabase() {
            disposable.add(viewModel.insertAllContactsToDataBase()
                .doOnError {
                    Timber.e("Insert error")
                }
                .subscribe({
                    Timber.d("Contacts saved")
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
            )
        }

        private fun cleanContactListOfDatabase(){
            disposable.add(viewModel.cleanContactList()
                .doOnError {
                    Timber.e("clean table error")

                }
                .subscribe({
                    Timber.e("Table cleaned")
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
            )
        }
```

To resume the problem, the subscribe method of the `viewModel.getContactFromDatabase()` is triggered without the call of the function `getContactsFromDatabase()`.
Open the app without any network (there are contacts displayed from the local db);
Open any network (wifi or 4g);
Try a swipe refresh to pull contacts from the API;
The subscribe of the `getContacts()` is triggered (normal);
The subscribe of the `viewModel.getContactFromDatabase()` is triggered without even the call of the function `getContactsFromDatabase()` -- PROBLEM

You can check my code on [Github](https://github.com/alexandre-thauvin/contact_list)

Comment: I'm just guessing here - but could it be that your `ContactDao` class is emitting contacts again, for some reason? `ContactDao.getContacts()` returns an `Observable`, so theoretically it could be emitting more than once...

Comment: What I mean is that it gets called once, but emits twice. Looks like @Minhtdh found evidence that's what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following these docs:

[room/accessing-data#query-rxjava](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-rxjava)

[room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)

> Flowable/Observable
>
> Every time the user data is updated, the Flowable object will emit automatically, allowing you to update the UI based on the latest data.

In your code, after `getContactByPages()` you call `saveContactsToDatabase()` to save the data to database

So `viewModel.getContactFromDatabase()` (which is point to `ContactDao.getContacts()`) will emit data again.

If you want `ContactDao.getContacts()` to emit only one time when is called, consider to convert `ContactDao.getContacts()` to `MayBe`/`Single` instead of `Observable`

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was exactly the problem. Indeed after reading the doc and replaced `Observable` by `Single` it works like a charm! Thanks for the help!